# update a line graph using swift

Tags: ios, swift

first of all, I am using this repository [click here](https://github.com/tmdvs/CoreGraphicsGraph)

I wanted to feed the values of the graph based on activity percentage(int), for example, I added a new activity, sunday 10%, the graph will update, but then when I update it on monday 30%,the value of sunday changes as well, how do I add a value that will not affect the first input.

Thanks!

edit: [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mw4ta11tlj63ubx/Screenshot%202015-02-10%2015.18.25.png?dl=0)

Comment: You forgot the link to the repository... :)

Comment: @JoelHinz ooppss! fixed it :)

Comment: Would you be able show exactly what you did to the data array?

Comment: @KyleMassacre I uploaded a screenshot, none really, I just want to know the algorithm goes cause I can't figure it out. I'm thinking of storing every progress value into data core.

Comment: Quite a bit of missing information here.  Where's the code you're using to populate the graph?  Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for pointers on getting questions answered.